# Import xls with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've done a java application where I can export to xls data files that are inside my application. The problem is that now I need to import them back and make the change of the data that have been changed in the xls file into the application using some kind of loop repeat to change all the data, using the code column as reference for the change within the application

The export code

```
 // File and chooser
    private File file;
    private FileInputStream fis;
    private JFileChooser chooser;

    // Date properties
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    // Apache POI properties
    private HSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private HSSFSheet sheet;
    private HSSFRow row;

    // Index
    private int index;

    // Properties
    private Dao<Stock> daoStock = null;

    private List<Stock> stockList;

    public void exportStockToXls() // Export XLS files
        {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            sheet = workbook.createSheet("Estoque");

            // File name
            file = new File("Estoque.xls");

            // File chooser
            chooser = new JFileChooser();

            // Chooser properties
            chooser.setDialogTitle("Exportar para XLS");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            chooser.setFileFilter(null);

            chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter()
            {
                @Override
                public String getDescription()
                {
                    return "XLS File"; // Chooser description
                }

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File f)
                {
                    return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("xls"); // File name
                }
            });

            int action = chooser.showSaveDialog(null); // Store user choice

            if (action == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) // Checks the user's choice
            {
                file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                String fileString = file.toString();

                if (fileString.toLowerCase().endsWith("xls") == false)
                {
                    fileString += ".xls";
                    file = new File(fileString);
                }

                // Search for data to export
                try
                {
                    daoStock = new SerializerStock();
                    stockList = daoStock.searchAll();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                index = 0;

                // Exporting
                for (Stock stock : stockList)
                {
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(index);
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(stock.getCode());
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(stock.getProductName());
                    row.createCell(2).setCellValue(stock.getSalePrice());

                    index++;
                }

                try
                {
                    workbook.write(file); // Write file
                    workbook.close(); // Closing flow after export
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arquivo exportado com sucesso!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao exportar arquivo!", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

The beginning of import code, i can't think more what i can do

```
public void importStockToXls() throws IOException // Import XLS files
    {
        // Chooser properties
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Importar Arquivos XLS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        chooser.setFileFilter(null);

        int showOpenDialog = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser.getParent()); // Stores user choice

        if (showOpenDialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) // Checks the user's choice
        {
            file = chooser.getSelectedFile(); // Get the file way if approved
        }

        fis = new FileInputStream(file); // Points to an instance of the file

        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis); // Passing FIS to workbook representation

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // Pick the page to be used

        // TODO
        fis.close(); // Closes instance flow
```

Change function

```
public void change(Stock obj) throws Exception
    {
        // Retrieve the code
        int code = obj.getCode();

        // Run to entire list behind the same recovered code
        for (Stock search : stockList)
        {
            // If the code find is the same recovered change data
            if (search.getCode() == code)
            {
                // Retrieve the information on the fields and change data
                search.setProductName(obj.getProductName());
                search.setSalePrice(obj.getSalePrice());
                search.setCostPrice(obj.getCostPrice());
                search.setNetProfit(obj.getNetProfit());

                // Saving changes
                writeFiles();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I want to import the xls file that the system itself generates, and change the information inside the system based on what was changed inside the xls file.

Comment: So what is your problem

Comment: I do not know how to get the information from each row of all the columns of every xls file and make the change inside my system where the files are serialized

Comment: "I do not know how to get the information from each row of all the columns": [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) -> [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) -> [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Getting+the+cell+contents)